# Why to use 'self' foreignkey in Django Models?

Tags: python, django

I've seen this pattern many times but I am not sure why people use it and would like to learn.

Here is small copy paste on what I mean: Category class is a blog post category which has the foreign key relationship to self. What do I gain for having such a relationship?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=32)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is the post entry for the same model. Here I find it obvious you would want to have entry category as key or user if this blog had user system.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=32, default='', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Comment: This enables a category to be a sub-category of another category. Essentially this creates a tree structure to your categories. Or, if you connect them in a cycle, I suppose, you could make other strange topologies.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. My naive version would have used another model lets say "subcategory" with key relationship to category. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here by using foreign key relationship to self you can have a hierarchical structure for your categories. Like parent categories and subcategories. In previous versions it was **TreeForeignKey**.